# Is it possible to have the gcd of 2 polynomials be the same in all fields?

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

So I have the polynomials $f(x) = x^3+x^2+x$ and $g(x)=x^2+x+1$

We are told to find the $gcd$ of both these polynomials in $Q[x], Z/3Z[x], Z/5Z[x], Z/11Z[x]$

After applying the Euclidean algorithm, I see that:

$x^3+x^2+x = x(x^2+x+1) + 0$

Thus the gcd is $x^2+x+1$

However, when I attempt to do the same in all the other fields, I end up with the same answer. I am doing this incorrectly or is it actually possible to have the same gcd in all fields?

Comment: Are you certain that you have the correct polynomials? Also, note that the $\gcd$ of $f$ and $f$ is $f$ over any field, for any $f$, so something like that is definitely possible.

Comment: Yes, the polynomials are correct.

Comment: If those are really the right polynomials, then it's a silly question. No need to use the Euclidean algorithm: $g$ divides $f$, so obviously their GCD is just $g$.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. To be honest, it did seem a bit weird to me as well!